# How to check if woocommerce is activated in theme

Tags: php, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm creating a theme with woocommerce which has the following:

```
<ul>

  <li>
    <?php 
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){ 
    ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) ); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'My Account', 'woothemes' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'My Account', 'woothemes' ); ?></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) ); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'Sign-in', 'woothemes' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Sign-in', 'woothemes' ); ?></a>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="<?php echo get_option( 'home' ) . '/' . 'my-lists/' ?>" title="My Wishlist">Wishlist</a>
  </li>

  <!--
  <li><a href="#" title="Email updates">Email Updates</a></li>
  -->
  <li> 
    <?php 
    global $woocommerce; 
    ?>
    <a id="header-ShoppingCart" class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart', 'woothemes' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf( _n( '%d item', 'My Bag (%d)', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes' ), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count ); ?> - <span id="header-cartCount"><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></span></a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

However this breaks the site if the woocommerce plugin is not activated. How can I check if the woocommerce plugin is activated?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could check to see if the 'WooCommerce' class exists, then run the code that requires WooCommerce.

```
<?php
if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
  // code that requires WooCommerce
} else {
  // you don't appear to have WooCommerce activated
}
?>
```

Comment: `class_exists('WooCommerce')` is going to return false, if the code is placed in functions.php while "activating plugin" ( the plugin is going to be activated after you check for WooCommerce class ).

Comment: So this would be false if someone happened to load the page at the exact moment that the plugin was being activated?

Comment: You can't really load at the "exact moment", you can load 1ms before or after. 

It's important to pay attention here, because, if you declare some Woo function for a condition where WooCommerce doesn't exist ( like your own `is_woocommerce()` ), then you will receive a fatal error when trying to activate WooCommerce Plugin, because you will register your function first, and only then WooCommerce is going to try to register their `is_woocommerce()` function, and that is going to cause a fatal error and prevent WooCommerce plugin from ever activating.

Comment: How would that prevent WooCommerce from loading?  If you named a function that happened to be the same as something within WooCommerce?

Comment: It would trigger a `Fatal Error, "Cannot redeclare function is_woocommerce"`. Try it.

Comment: Right, but my point is that it would only fail if you declared a function that was also declared in WooCommerce.  Simply detecting it's existence in a theme, as stated in the question, wouldn't be affected by this.

Comment: Yep, And I'm not arguing with you, I'm just posting relevant information, just in case someone decides to redeclare a function if WooCommerce doesn't exist

Answer (score 12):

To check if woocommerce or anyother plguin is active, paste the following code on the template where you want to display the message.

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    echo 'WooCommerce is active.';
} else {
    echo 'WooCommerce is not Active.';
}
```

Comment: This answer appears to be the official way to do it. See https://docs.woothemes.com/document/create-a-plugin/ .

Comment: This is wrong, as it does not work on multisite, their documentation is wrong, use class_exist instead.

Comment: class_exist doesn't detect woocommerce on multisite for me (WP 5.4.1, WC 4.1) @Arshid KK's answer below does : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/274000/34517

Answer (score 9):

Use following code. It will work on multi site also.

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
if ( is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php') ) {
  // Do what you want in case woocommerce is installed
}
```

Comment: As of now this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would perform the class check once all plugins are loaded. Because in some cases it can return false negative.

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'see_all_plugins_loaded' );

function see_all_plugins_loaded() {
   if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
       // do your stuff
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The new [official way](https://woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/#section-1) to do it with multisite support:

```
// Test to see if WooCommerce is active (including network activated).
$plugin_path = trailingslashit( WP_PLUGIN_DIR ) . 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php';

if (
    in_array( $plugin_path, wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins() )
    || in_array( $plugin_path, wp_get_active_network_plugins() )
) {
    // Custom code here. WooCommerce is active, however it has not 
    // necessarily initialized (when that is important, consider
    // using the `woocommerce_init` action).
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
$is_woo = (function_exist('is_woocommerce') || class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) );
if($is_woo){
    // WooCommerce Is Active
}else{
    // WooCommerce Isn't Active
}
```

you can use this easy method too:

```
function kdev_is_active_woocommerce(){
    return  (function_exists('is_woocommerce') || class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) || ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) );
}
if(kdev_is_active_woocommerce()){
    // WooCommerce Is Active
}else{
    // WooCommerce Isn't Active
}
```